# I can see the metrics using localhost:9106/metrics but NOT in the web console from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a issue, I can see the metrics using localhost:9106/metrics

```
TYPE aws_applicationelb_new_connection_count_sum gauge
aws_applicationelb_new_connection_count_sum{job="aws_applicationelb",instance="",load_balancer="XXX",} 275.0 1695258240000
aws_applicationelb_new_connection_count_sum{job="aws_applicationelb",instance="",load_balancer="XXXXX",} 2.0 1695258180000
aws_applicationelb_new_connection_count_sum{job="aws_applicationelb",instance="",load_balancer="XXXXX",} 478.0 1695258240000
aws_applicationelb_new_connection_count_sum{job="aws_applicationelb",instance="",load_balancer="XXXX",} 1.0 1695258000000
aws_applicationelb_new_connection_count_sum{job="aws_applicationelb",instance="",load_balancer="XXX",} 3.0 1695258060000
aws_applicationelb_new_connection_count_sum{job="aws_applicationelb",instance="",load_balancer="XXXXX",} 4.0 1695258180000
```

But when I want to see these same metrics in the Prometheus Web it doesn´t appear!
How can I get the metrics in the Prometheus Web?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdwDU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XXWe.png)

Thank you!

I would like to see metrics from cloudWatch exporter in Prometheus Web

Comment: This question being about configuration is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Also, when asking this question on [devops.se], [su] or [sf] don't forget to include information about if your target (Status > Targets) is shown as up.